# Determinant of the tensor matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, tensors

I have a data:

[image]

As an example, it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Then, when I try to take Det[]:
[image]

**How we can find determinant value of these kind of matrices ?**

Comment: I thought determinant is only defined for square matrices?

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to find this matrix's value. I only know determinant. Is there a way to find values for these kind of matrices ?

Comment: "Yes, but I am trying to find this matrix's value. I only know determinant. Is there a way to find values for these kind of matrices ?" That does not make sense. You do not have a matrix. `FA` is a rank 4 tensor. Maybe you want to convert it to a matrix first? So `Det[ArrayReshape[FA, {1, 1} 15 127]]` might help you. Also `ArrayFlatten` might be of interest when you are working with block matrices...

Comment: Can you include a precise definition of the quantity you want to compute? "Determinant", as is usually understood, does not apply to the object (tensor) you have here.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher oh wow, thank you. I was mistaken then. I see that it is only a tensor.

Comment: @Szabolcs Basically, I am calculating this: http://hopfion.com/hopf.html, the integral, at the end, should be equal to or close to 1.